# Can I pass a MYSQL function as a value through an HTML Form?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, function

I have an HTML form that I'm using to submit some SQL data. I'd like to pass the MYSQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() as a value but when I do this there are single tick marks that get added the the function upon insert and it fails, like this 'LAST_INSERT_ID()'.

I want to be able to use this function so I can call what that ID was.

Is it possible to pass this function successfully?

Comment: can you show your code, please

Comment: yes, please show the code, and then tell us which url we can try it out on...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass SQL code instead of values and have it automatically executed on the server.

(Can you imagine how that could have been used by someone with not so good intentions...?)

You could send a special "magic" value, that the code on the server would recognise, and change the query to use `last_insert_id()` for the value. (You could use the function name as magic value, but you should probably use something less obvious.)

To insert code in a query like that, you need to create the SQL query dynamically. When you create queries dynamically, make sure to escape values properly so that the code isn't open to SQL injection attacks.